# Routed not found 404 error but routes exist in laravel

Tags: laravel

My Routes

```
Route::get('/', 'TasksController@index')->name('task.index');
Route::get('/task', 'TasksController@create')->name('task.create');
Route::post('/task', 'TasksController@store')->name('task.store');
```

My Task Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Task;
class TasksController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    # code...
    return view('welcome');
}

public function create()
{
    # code...
    return view('tasks');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    # code...
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    Task::create([
        'name' => $request->name
    ]);

    return redirect('/');
}
```

}

My Task Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
protected $table = "tasks";
protected $primaryKey = "id";
protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

PROBLEM:
Problem is that on create route i just call a view and Error 404 show display I called with route name but sam proble encounter task view only show on "/" this index route. Please sort out the proble,

Comment: trying to understand a bit. you get a 404 when visiting /task ?

Comment: You showed us one side of the problem - the backend that defines the routes, and the controller that handles them.  The other side of the problem is the front end - what actual routes are you using? How are they generated?  Do they render correctly in your HTML?  Show us your (relevant) view code.

Comment: How did you call the create route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
return redirect()->route('task.index');
```

**Your store Function**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    # code...
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    Task::create([
        'name' => $request->name
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('task.index');
}
```